# Create two columns in html or php

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

I'd like to make 2 column filled with data on the woo commerce single product page.
I have these lines of code

```html
Audiofiles: 
<?php

echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field_audiofiles', true );
?>
<BR>
Format: 
<?php
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field_format', true );
?>
<BR>

Bitrate: 
<?php
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_select_bitrate', true );
?>
<BR>

Samplerate:
<?php
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_select_samplerate', true );
?>
```

Using columns would be prettier because the columns would align the text.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr style="height:50px">
<td style="width:50%;height:50px">
<?php
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field_audiofiles', true );
?>
</td>
<td style="width:50%;height:50px">
<?php
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field_format', true );
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:50px">
<td style="width:50%;height:50px">
<?php
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_select_bitrate', true );
?>
</td>
<td style="width:50%;height:50px">
<?php
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_select_samplerate', true );
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```